# JavaFX - Установить нужный layout через scene.setRoot() по бездействию

Tags: javafx

Приложение на **JavaFX**. Есть сцена, она всегда одна, меняется только **Root**. Есть много `Button`, `Label`, `ImageView`, `MediaView`, `ScrollPane` и так далее.

Мне необходимо: что бы по бездействию в течении n минут, устанавливался нужный layout через `scene.setRoot()`.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, но, вероятно, не оптимальный, т.к. эвентов будет много; сервис после можно перезапустить по своему внутреннему событию:

```
private class WaitService extends Service {

    private static final long WAIT_TIME = 10*1000L;//10 sec
    public long lastChange = System.currentTimeMillis();

    @Override
    protected Task createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                while ( true ) {
                    System.out.println( "check " + ( System.currentTimeMillis() - lastChange ) );
                    if ( ( System.currentTimeMillis() - lastChange ) > WAIT_TIME ) {
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        try {
                            Thread.currentThread().sleep( 500 );
                        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    ...

    WaitService service = new WaitService();

    EventDispatcher origDispetcher = stage.getEventDispatcher();
    mscene.setEventDispatcher( new EventDispatcher() {
        @Override
        public Event dispatchEvent( Event event, EventDispatchChain tail ) {
            if ( service.isRunning() ) {
                //тут какой-нибудь фильтр
                System.out.println( "!!" );
                service.lastChange = System.currentTimeMillis();                   
            }
            return origDispetcher.dispatchEvent( event, tail );
        }
    } );

    service.setOnSucceeded( e -> {
        scene.setRoot( new StackPane( new Text( "Hooray" ) ) );
    } );
    service.restart();

    stage.setScene( scene );
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку, пригодилось.